# how to build in Keras Many to Many LTSM with Softmax Layer at the end of each time step

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network, softmax

I am struggling to create a many to many LTSM with a `softmax` at the end of each time step.

I have built:

- an input of (400 samples, 2 time steps, 8 input dimensions per time step)
- a `softmax` output to recognize 5 different ranks:
  (400 samples, 2 time steps, 5 input dimensions per time step)

```
ranks   0  1  2  3  4 
i.e.  [[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
       [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

- Note: `XX` dim `(400,2,8)`
- Note: `YY` dim `(400,2,5)`

Then I try to run it after splitting between train and test sets,

but no matter what I change, I keep getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [64,5] and labels shape [320]
     [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWith#Logits (defined at \Local\Temp/ipykernel_14204/3401061264.py:9) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_46581]"
```

I have spent two days without any progress. I will appreciate an expert advice.

This is my model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(8, input_shape=(dim_XX[1],dim_XX[2]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(5,input_shape=(dim_YY[1],dim_YY[2]),activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=opt,
        metrics=['accuracy'],
   )

model.fit(X_train,
              y_train,
              epochs=1,
              validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Set loss to `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`

Comment: I am a bit confused about the "units" on the ltsm(unit...

Comment: If I one to do a one to many
             output
              |
0--------0
|             |
input_t1 input t2

input(samples,2xtimesteps, 8 features)